# introduce logging without source code pollution

Tags: c#, .net, logging

this question is nagging in my head for some time now... For logging to be useful it should be every there in the code, but then it makes code hard to read. Like the following code:

```
public IDictionary<decimal, Status> GetStatus(decimal[] keys)
{
    _logger.Debug("ENTERED GetStatus");

    IDictionary<decimal, Status> statuses = new Dictionary<decimal, Status>();
    string inClause = null;

    inClause = FormatInClause(keys, inClause);
    _logger.DebugFormat(" inClause: '{0}' ", inClause);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inClause))
    {
        _logger.Error("Key collection is null or empty.");
        throw new Exception("Key collection is null or empty.");
    }

    if (!IsOpen)
        Connection.Open();

    using (IDbCommand cmd = Connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = " select id, date, status " +
            " from ORDERS where id in ( " + inClause + " ) ";

        inClause = null;

        using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                object[] values = new object[reader.FieldCount];

                reader.GetValues(values);
                DebugHelper.LogValues(_logger, " reader.Read() #" + i + " reader.GetValues(values): ", values);

                statuses[(decimal)values[0]] = new Status(
                    (decimal)values[0],
                    ValueOrDefult<string>(values[1]),
                    ValueOrDefult<string>(values[2]),
                    (decimal)values[3],
                    ValueOrDefult<DateTime>(values[4]));
                _logger.DebugFormat(" reader.Read() #{0} created new Status() ", i);

                values = null;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    _logger.Debug("EXITED GetStatus");
    return statuses;
}
```

Is there some strategy for logging not to reduce readability of source code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Aspect oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) is supposed to help with [cross-cutting concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern) like logging, eg. [postsharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) but you cannot really have very fine grained control over what is logged unless you resort to more traditional methods

Comment: Agreed.  PostSharp will handle the enter / exit type logging. I've used it for this very thing.  The cool thing is PostSharp can actually write out the values of the arguments.

Comment: @Pondidum I'm a hungry little rep troll

Comment: @Darius No biggie, lots of other folk here could have steered you there as well, I just had the fastest reflexes :P

Answer (score 3):

imho your logging is cluttered because your code is so too. You should read up on SOLID principles.

For instance, move the reader code to a separate method.

Comment: thanks I will look into problems your pointed to in my example

Answer (score 1):

You can follow a couple rules.

1) Only log errors where you are actually "dealing" with them.

2) Use AOP to wrap your methods so you don't have to have debuging statements on enter and exit of all methods.  You can also have the AOP calls log the in-coming and out-going parameters/responses of methods.

Answer (score 0):

Look at an aspect weaver such as [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp)

Answer (score -2):

Your source code looks fine to me... Actually it looks best that way, because I can see the log messages and figure what's in between each 2 messages.

Even though, one thing is bothering me, it's indeed the **_** in **_logger**.

Some logging apis tend to propose a shortened API like:

```
l.d("debug")
l.c("critical")
...etc
```

The way above or your way are both nice imho.

**EDIT**

If you still want to do something about it, just wrap your logging lines into #regions and collapse them.

Comment: I do not agree about the naming standard. All variables and method names should be descriptive, including those for logging. Mixing standards in code makes it harder to read.

Comment: Imho it's a matter of taste. If you do you the kind of l.c("") stuff but **only** for your debugging, I don't think this would hurt the source readability at all. Actually it would highlight the messages themselves rather than what logging function is called. I've used both until today, and I haven't had readability issues at all.